# Monolithic alembic animation file not playing smoothly

Tags: animation, alembic

I am generating an ocean sim in houdini, and exporting it to a monolithic alembic file.
When I load it back into houdini, it plays smoothly.
i.e. it plays every frame.
However, when I import it into blender, it will play a few frames smoothly, then it will hold the animation for two frames, then continue playing.
Then it will repeat the above pattern.
Has anyone else seen this?
If so, is there a fix/work around?
thanks